# Difference between Qt Embedded and Qt for Desktop

Tags: qt

I have seen so many documentation about Qt Embedded and Qt for Desktop. But not clear about the difference. Can anybody please explain the differences?

Answer (score 2):

Qt for DEsktop LInuxQt/X11 is built on top of the x11 window system, but Qt for Embedded Linux provides its
own window system and has therefore lower RAM and ROM requirements. With
Qt for Embedded Linux, applications will access the display directly for optimal
graphics performance. Nonetheless, the API for developing applications is the
same for Qt/X11 and Qt for Embedded Linux.

Comment: I think this answer summarizes it the best. The difference is pretty much the existence of QWS and the APIs are the same. On Qt5 the distinction doesn't exist anymore.

Answer (score 1):

As kernel maniac said, Qt for Linux is built on top of the X11 server. Qt for Embedded Linux instead provides its own Window System names QWS. With respect to X11 it is smaller in memory and draws directly to the framebuffer or might take advantage of other libraries to write, like DirectFB.

With respect to X11 it is far less advanced and it is difficult to add hardware acceleration to it. I suppose this is one of the main reasons why they dropped completely Qt on Embedded Linux in Qt 5.0. So consider that it is not available anymore. It is replaced by drivers implemented using QPA.

Answer (score 0):

QT Embedded is desigined in order to build applications for embedded systems .

If you don't know what that is you can click [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embedded_system) .

Qt for Desktop is used to deploy applications to the popular operating systems such as Linux, Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Currently (Qt 4.8.3) the two links for Linux/X11 and embedded Linux point to the same file: http://releases.qt-project.org/qt4/source/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.8.3.tar.gz

I suspect there used to be differences (maybe from when Digia was responsible for creating a patched Qt for certain platforms?), but that that is no longer the case. Looking at the Qt archive (ftp://ftp.qt.nokia.com/qt/source/), it appears that a different, specific 'embedded' distribution of Qt ended after 4.5.x.